# Mysql Cursor with Trigger: Same table update multiple time on single cursor

Tags: mysql, triggers, cursor

I have two table categories with fields.

```
id parent_id name   enabled
---------------------------
1    0       abc     1
2    1       mnc     1
```

another table brand_master

```
id category_id name   admin_status
---------------------------
1    1         pqr     1
2    2         xyz     1
```

I need to update brands table "admin_status" field on the base of category "enabled" field update.

I have following Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `category_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `categories`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE brand_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE brand_master_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE selected_id INT; 

/**brand record updateed start**/
BEGIN
DECLARE brand_master_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT brand_master.id FROM `brand_master`
 INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id=brand_master.category_id WHERE c.parent_id=old.id;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET brand_master_finished = 1;
 OPEN brand_master_cursor;
 get_email: LOOP
 FETCH brand_master_cursor INTO selected_id;
 IF brand_master_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_email;
 END IF;
 UPDATE brand_master SET admin_status=new.enabled WHERE `category_id` = old.id;
 UPDATE brand_master SET admin_status=new.enabled WHERE brand_master.id = selected_id;

 END LOOP get_email;
 CLOSE brand_master_cursor; 
 END;
 /** end**/
END
```

I have tried to use two cursor for parent categorie's brand update and then child categories brand update. but it only update only parent categorie's brand. 
So i have created above one cursor combining both update queries into single.
But in above it updates only parent categories brand when parent category disabled/enabled. If i disable/enable child category then it does not update only child category.

ex. if i update category id "1" enabled=0 then both brands admin_status=0 updated. 
but if i update category id "2" enabled=0 then nothing is updated.

Any help please. How to update same table twice in single cursor with different conditions?

Comment: You want to update parent, grandparent, great grandparent all the way up the chain and do you want to also update child, grandchild and great grandchild all the way down the chain?

Comment: yes. i want to update parent and child tables